# не распознаются устройства Ubuntu 16.04 и отладка по usb [andoid studio]

Tags: ubuntu, android-studio

[image: img]

```
 $ adb devices
List of devices attached
```

Само устройство распознается системой, а вот android studio отказывается видеть устройства. Файл [прав прописан](http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html)
Опции разработчика включены, провода usb исправны

Comment: Переключение на PTP\MTP не помогло

Comment: Опции разработчика да, а отладка в них?

Comment: Ну естественно включена, я на винде же дебажил, вот Ubuntu поставил и пошли проблемы)

Answer (score 1):

Все проблема решена, adb требовал прав администратора для прослушивания порта...

```
$ sudo su
$ adb kill-server
$ adb start-server
```

или

```
$ adb root
```

Comment: Это странно, у меня работает ADB без рута. Если это решает проблему, хорошо, но она явно зарыта в другом месте.

Comment: Согласен, на 14 ubuntu оно тоже работало без требования рута. Ну пока так.. поищу ещё, где может быть проблема. Может кто ответит тут.